# Cannot save link in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to save a link to a db using codeigniter
The link looks like http://example.com

The validation rules are

```
trim|required|xss_clean|callback__check_campaign_model
```

The custom function expects the input to be either the word local or a link as below

```
public function _check_campaign_model($str)
    {
        if($str !== "local" && filter_var($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) == FALSE)
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('_check_campaign_model', 'The provided %s campaign_model is invalid.');
            return FALSE;
        }else{
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```

Problem is, when I save the word "local" to the database it works well. 
When I try saving a link... I get the error below
[image: bug]

I have checked and seen that `$this->form_validation->run()`  is false and when I `echo validation_errors()`, it is empty.

Help out

Answer (score 1):

The link you have added is redirecting to login page and giving a 403 forbidden since fetcher is not logged in
I would use regex.

```
<?php 
function validate_url($url) {
return (bool)preg_match("
    /^                                                      # Start at the beginning of the text
  (?:ftp|https?|feed):\/\/                                # Look for ftp, http, https or feed schemes
    (?:                                                     # Userinfo (optional) which is typically
      (?:(?:[\w\.\-\+!$&'\(\)*\+,;=]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+:)*      # a username or a username and password
      (?:[\w\.\-\+%!$&'\(\)*\+,;=]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+@          # combination
    )?
    (?:
    (?:[a-z0-9\-\.]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+                        # A domain name or a IPv4 address
    |(?:\[(?:[0-9a-f]{0,4}:)*(?:[0-9a-f]{0,4})\])         # or a well formed IPv6 address
    )
  (?::[0-9]+)?                                            # Server port number (optional)
    (?:[\/|\?]
    (?:[\w#!:\.\?\+=&@$'~*,;\/\(\)\[\]\-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})   # The path and query (optional)
    *)?
  $/xi", $url);
 }
 ?>
```

Code not well formatted am on my phone

Comment: Awesome.. let me try it out

Comment: Replace filter_var with validate_url

Comment: Replace filter_var with validate_url

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do 'direct script access'. You are not 'allowed' to load the page directly (aka to a .php page). 
I have no knowledge how your htaccess or routes are, or even what URL you want to access but if you get a 403 error: it is something totally different than a bad database request!

Comment: Well, I do not know your entire code. Good chance you might redirect him/her to a different page on 'success' vs failure. Maybe there is actually something wrong and he gets send to a other page. The fact is that the actual error you are posting (the 403) comes from direct script access. Like every file has:  <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');